# Javascript API is working fine on the main site, but fails to work on an external server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api

This code can be used in conjuction with jQuery to embed a button on a page letting users share a link to my site.

```
<div class="button" data-text="Button text" data-url="http://externalserver.com">
</div>
<script src="http://mainserver.co.uk/api.js"></script>
```

The javascript file has to use xmlHTTPrequest to connect with php files to check whether or not you are logged in or not, and to then post the comment on my site. It is very simple, as all you need to do is click the button it creates. Or not.
Well, it works fine on any page on http://mainserver.co.uk, but on my external server, it just shows console errors such as

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load filename. Origin http://externalserver.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Well I know this must be possible because twitter, google and facebook can all do it, so why can't I?
**EDIT**
Ok, thanks. but this is still a problem.
Users have sessions on the mainsite which tells the webpage that they are logged in.
Using this code, I can test that.

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
if (isset($_SESSION["user"]))
{
    echo "0";
}
else
{
    echo "1";
}
?>
```

When I am logged in and run this code, it Returns 0 on the main site, but 1 on the external site, as if I am only logged in when testing on the main site

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Read more here: http://websitez.com/javascript-cross-domain-post-get/

Comment: @SLaks, how do twitter, google + and facebook avoid this?

Comment: @user2751288: Read further in that Wikipedia article.

Comment: @SLaks its kindof working but I need help still

Comment: If your sessions work by using cookies for passing the session id, then of course this does not work – because you send a request from a different domain, so no cookies for your “main” domain are send with this request. No cookie == no active session == no logged in user.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe but how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

> Origin http://externalserver.com is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

- its a cross domain ajax issue(Read more: [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), [cross domain requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-domain_requests))

If your JavaScript runs on example.com and the server you are requesting to is in example.net. Make sure it allows the page your js is running by this header

```
   <?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com/ajax.html'); ?>
```

or

```
   <?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

(the wildcard is going to allow any domain to send requests to your host. I recommend replacing the asterisk with a specific domain that you will be running scripts on)

Also you need to send Origin header from ajax to the server

```
Origin: http://example.com/ajax.html
```

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load filename.

- is because you didn't specify full url in you ajax request. But it works with your main server because you run php in the same domain itself.

Comment: Thankyou, but can you tell me why the external server cannot detect the session on the main server even though I have allowed access to all domains and added session_start()

Comment: Sorry, can you explain more?

Comment: Session support in PHP consists of a way to preserve certain data across subsequent accesses. Its a common logic that session set in one server cannot be read by any other server.

Comment: Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Nope. Its not possible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39069/discussion-between-user2751288-and-harish-anchu)

Comment: If you wanna know user is logged in you may need to do a pre ajax call to main server. And send whether user is logged in or not to your button script server on click.

Comment: What is a pre ajax call?

Comment: I just meant an ajax call before your button ajax call.

Comment: the ajax code to check if users are logged in or not is at the very start of the javascript file