# Is it possible for a server to read the sessions of another server through xmlHTTPrequest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, session

I ask this question because it **must** be possible, as twitter, google and facebook all do it within their social buttons.
I use this ajax code from the file `socialbuttons.js` on server 1

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://server1.com/checkifuserisloggedin',
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
        if (response == 0)
        {
            login = true;
        }
    }
});
```

The code at http://server1.com/checkifuserisloggedin is

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
if (isset($_SESSION["user"]))
{
    echo "0";
}
else
{
    echo "1";
}
```

For some reason, when i put a link to `socialbuttons.js` on server 2, it cannot tell that the session is active and returns 1 whether the user is logged in or not.
If not possible with sessions, how can I do this?

Comment: Do you know where facebook, twitter saves the session data?  is it in database or shared machine?#

Comment: I have no idea but im guessing in a session cookie like everyone else

Comment: You cannot "read the sessions of another server" - end of.  If you have control over both servers then you can put a script on either of them that will respond with session values when asked, but you can't (for example) just say "domain.com.session[var]" - that would be utterly ridiculous.

Comment: Thats just a cookie for identify the session key in server. but where the session data get stored?

Comment: @Archer, so why is twitter allowed to but I am not?

Comment: Twitter is not allowed to.  What you are asking is not possible.  If you're talking about social media interaction on different sites then they require you to login at least once, which then gives that app the authorisation required to perform tasks via an api (usually via some form of token stored as a cookie).

Comment: *"twitter, google and facebook all do it within their social buttons"*  no they don't. When you sign into twitter on one site, a cookie is set on your machine for the twitter domain that persists for x hours or days. Any time you visit a site that uses said twitter widget, the server it communicates with will be able to read the cookie because it's the server that set it.

Comment: @Archer how can I do that within my `socialbuttons.js`

Comment: You've not actually told us what you're trying to do.

Comment: Duplicate of [Javascript API is working fine on the main site, but fails to work on an external server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318683/javascript-api-is-working-fine-on-the-main-site-but-fails-to-work-on-an-externa) (Maybe rather a follow-up, but still no real need for a second question, especially if the code shown is still the same.)

Comment: @Archer Im trying to make something so people can put a button on their site and when they press it then it puts a comment onto my site

Comment: The easiest way is probably an iframe.  You give someone some "embed code" and they put it on their site, but it opens a page on your site with whatever controls you want on it.  As for them being logged on, I think that's a bad idea as it means they would have to have logged onto your site since opening their browser, in order to use controls on someone else's site.  A cookie would be much friendlier than that, but there are still a lot of things to consider.  This is not a simple task, unless you want to forget about security and just let anyone post.

Comment: ok im going to scrap this idea and make it locally on my site only instead but thanks for your help @Archer

Comment: No worries.  Sorry it wasn't good news, but it's a massive task (to do it right).

Comment: Another trick used by "like" buttons is to do a GET request on an image file by inserting a hidden `<img>` tag. Any tiny icon will do. Your server sees this get request and logs it as a "like" vote (obviously, don't serve the image as static!). The request for the image, since it's to the site's URL will contain whatever cookie that has been set by that site before.